# Sorting polynomials based on their y value and finding their intersection

Tags: plotting, polynomials, sorting, maximum

I've got the following list of polynomials,

```
f=<|{"a", "b"} -> (2.88889 x + 158.568 x^2 + 972.426 x^3 + 
     2782.57 x^4 + 4689.15 x^5 + 6158.85 x^6 + 6193.35 x^7 + 
     4759.49 x^8 + 2828.1 x^9 + 1262.26 x^10 + 396.808 x^11 + 
     87.1035 x^12 + 15.9183 x^13 + 2.35827 x^14)/(2 x + 142 x^2 + 
     994 x^3 + 3068 x^4 + 5440 x^5 + 7516 x^6 + 8061 x^7 + 6591 x^8 + 
     4215 x^9 + 2029 x^10 + 694 x^11 + 181 x^12 + 33 x^13 + 
     4 x^14), {"a", 
   "c"} -> (1.92593 x + 154.859 x^2 + 1000.11 x^3 + 2910.7 x^4 + 
     4824.12 x^5 + 6433.15 x^6 + 6287.79 x^7 + 4729.91 x^8 + 
     2616.64 x^9 + 1072.34 x^10 + 300.412 x^11 + 66.1224 x^12 + 
     9.79591 x^13 + 1.17914 x^14)/(2 x + 142 x^2 + 994 x^3 + 
     3068 x^4 + 5440 x^5 + 7516 x^6 + 8061 x^7 + 6591 x^8 + 
     4215 x^9 + 2029 x^10 + 694 x^11 + 181 x^12 + 33 x^13 + 
     4 x^14), {"a", 
   "d"} -> (4.81481 x + 154.859 x^2 + 992.071 x^3 + 2876.3 x^4 + 
     4856.42 x^5 + 6212.28 x^6 + 6143.44 x^7 + 4685.55 x^8 + 
     2780.4 x^9 + 1173.81 x^10 + 376.34 x^11 + 87.7393 x^12 + 
     12.2449 x^13 + 1.76871 x^14)/(2 x + 142 x^2 + 994 x^3 + 
     3068 x^4 + 5440 x^5 + 7516 x^6 + 8061 x^7 + 6591 x^8 + 
     4215 x^9 + 2029 x^10 + 694 x^11 + 181 x^12 + 33 x^13 + 
     4 x^14), {"a", 
   "e"} -> (1.92593 x + 154.859 x^2 + 1177.81 x^3 + 3305.38 x^4 + 
     5174.38 x^5 + 6568.7 x^6 + 6234.04 x^7 + 4385.35 x^8 + 
     2365.3 x^9 + 900.93 x^10 + 255.515 x^11 + 41.9623 x^12 + 
     6.12244 x^13 + 1.17914 x^14)/(2 x + 142 x^2 + 994 x^3 + 
     3068 x^4 + 5440 x^5 + 7516 x^6 + 8061 x^7 + 6591 x^8 + 
     4215 x^9 + 2029 x^10 + 694 x^11 + 181 x^12 + 33 x^13 + 
     4 x^14), {"a", 
   "f"} -> (2.88889 x + 143.731 x^2 + 946.531 x^3 + 2706.91 x^4 + 
     4601.38 x^5 + 6048.02 x^6 + 6250.93 x^7 + 4803.85 x^8 + 
     2905.71 x^9 + 1305.46 x^10 + 423.878 x^11 + 103.634 x^12 + 
     18.9796 x^13 + 1.76871 x^14)/(2 x + 142 x^2 + 994 x^3 + 
     3068 x^4 + 5440 x^5 + 7516 x^6 + 8061 x^7 + 6591 x^8 + 
     4215 x^9 + 2029 x^10 + 694 x^11 + 181 x^12 + 33 x^13 + 4 x^14)|>;
```

I can plot then using,

```
Plot[f, {x, 0, 1.5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

which gives:

[image]

I wonder about two things:

1. It can be seen at some point around 1 on x axis the lines are intersected, how can I know where is this point of intersection exactly? 
   I know one can use

   `FindRoot[f[[1]] == f[[2]], {x, 1}]`

which gives:

```
{x -> 1.03846}
```

but we have more than one equation, in fact all of the intersect on above point but I want to know if there is a general way?

2. How can I sort the polynomials based on the highest value they have on y axis?

Comment: `Reduce[poly1==poly2&&x>1,x,Reals`] for every pair of your polynomials and I look at the roots near 1 and I round off to six digits then I get {x == 1.038468, x == 1.038475, x == 1.038463, x == 1.038454, x == 1.038463, x == 1.038460, x == 1.038464, x == 1.038460, x == 1.038465, x == 1.038462} so it is going to be hard to get "this point of intersection exactly"

Comment: If you use `Rationalize` to remove the decimals from the equations and then solve them 2 at a time, they don't actually meet at exactly the same point. `Solve[{Rationalize[f[[1]]==Rationalize[f[[2]]],8/10 < x < 2}, x, Reals]` gives 1.03846837 but eqs 2 and 3 give 1.03846251. Are they supposed to cross at precisely the same point? Or are you okay with just finding the x-value where there is the minimum difference? If they were precisely equal, you would be able to sue something like `Solve[f[[1]] == f[[2]] == f[[3]] == f[[4]] == f[[5]], x]`.

Answer (score 3):

1. A robust way of finding the best candidate for the intersection is to minimize the variance between the different curves:

   ```
   Minimize[Variance[f], x]
   (*    {3.06909*10^-14, {x -> 1.03846}}    *)
   ```
2. Sort the polynomials in `f` by their maximum (you may want to constrain the domain in which the maximum is searched):

   ```
   SortBy[f, Maximize[#, x][[1]] &]
   (*    lots of output    *)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

[`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) the polynomials

```
f = <|{"a", 
      "b"} -> (2.88889 x + 158.568 x^2 + 972.426 x^3 + 2782.57 x^4 + 
        4689.15 x^5 + 6158.85 x^6 + 6193.35 x^7 + 4759.49 x^8 + 
        2828.1 x^9 + 1262.26 x^10 + 396.808 x^11 + 87.1035 x^12 + 
        15.9183 x^13 + 2.35827 x^14)/(2 x + 142 x^2 + 994 x^3 + 
        3068 x^4 + 5440 x^5 + 7516 x^6 + 8061 x^7 + 6591 x^8 + 
        4215 x^9 + 2029 x^10 + 694 x^11 + 181 x^12 + 33 x^13 + 
        4 x^14) // 
    Rationalize[#, 0] &, {"a", 
      "c"} -> (1.92593 x + 154.859 x^2 + 1000.11 x^3 + 2910.7 x^4 + 
        4824.12 x^5 + 6433.15 x^6 + 6287.79 x^7 + 4729.91 x^8 + 
        2616.64 x^9 + 1072.34 x^10 + 300.412 x^11 + 66.1224 x^12 + 
        9.79591 x^13 + 1.17914 x^14)/(2 x + 142 x^2 + 994 x^3 + 
        3068 x^4 + 5440 x^5 + 7516 x^6 + 8061 x^7 + 6591 x^8 + 
        4215 x^9 + 2029 x^10 + 694 x^11 + 181 x^12 + 33 x^13 + 
        4 x^14) // 
    Rationalize[#, 0] &, {"a", 
      "d"} -> (4.81481 x + 154.859 x^2 + 992.071 x^3 + 2876.3 x^4 + 
        4856.42 x^5 + 6212.28 x^6 + 6143.44 x^7 + 4685.55 x^8 + 
        2780.4 x^9 + 1173.81 x^10 + 376.34 x^11 + 87.7393 x^12 + 
        12.2449 x^13 + 1.76871 x^14)/(2 x + 142 x^2 + 994 x^3 + 
        3068 x^4 + 5440 x^5 + 7516 x^6 + 8061 x^7 + 6591 x^8 + 
        4215 x^9 + 2029 x^10 + 694 x^11 + 181 x^12 + 33 x^13 + 
        4 x^14) // 
    Rationalize[#, 0] &, {"a", 
      "e"} -> (1.92593 x + 154.859 x^2 + 1177.81 x^3 + 3305.38 x^4 + 
        5174.38 x^5 + 6568.7 x^6 + 6234.04 x^7 + 4385.35 x^8 + 
        2365.3 x^9 + 900.93 x^10 + 255.515 x^11 + 41.9623 x^12 + 
        6.12244 x^13 + 1.17914 x^14)/(2 x + 142 x^2 + 994 x^3 + 
        3068 x^4 + 5440 x^5 + 7516 x^6 + 8061 x^7 + 6591 x^8 + 
        4215 x^9 + 2029 x^10 + 694 x^11 + 181 x^12 + 33 x^13 + 
        4 x^14) // 
    Rationalize[#, 0] &, {"a", 
      "f"} -> (2.88889 x + 143.731 x^2 + 946.531 x^3 + 2706.91 x^4 + 
        4601.38 x^5 + 6048.02 x^6 + 6250.93 x^7 + 4803.85 x^8 + 
        2905.71 x^9 + 1305.46 x^10 + 423.878 x^11 + 103.634 x^12 + 
        18.9796 x^13 + 1.76871 x^14)/(2 x + 142 x^2 + 994 x^3 + 
        3068 x^4 + 5440 x^5 + 7516 x^6 + 8061 x^7 + 6591 x^8 + 
        4215 x^9 + 2029 x^10 + 694 x^11 + 181 x^12 + 33 x^13 + 
        4 x^14) // Rationalize[#, 0] &|>;
```

Finding the pairwise intersections near `x == 1`

```
intersections = 
 NSolve[{#, 4/5 < x < 6/5}, x, 
     WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision][[1]] & /@ (Equal @@@ 
    Subsets[f[[#]] & /@ Range[Length[f]], {2}])

(* {{x -> 1.038468378686529}, {x -> 1.038474882506591}, {x -> 
   1.038463033375997}, {x -> 1.038454109438708}, {x -> 
   1.038462513865996}, {x -> 1.038459695030974}, {x -> 
   1.038463914367546}, {x -> 1.038460391885017}, {x -> 
   1.038464706661657}, {x -> 1.038461704012336}} *)
```

The intersections are in the interval

```
MinMax[x /. intersections]

(* {1.038454109438708, 1.038474882506591} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

[This is basically the same as @Roman's answer but in different language.]

Could minimize the sum of squares of pairwise differences. I discarded the denominators after checking they were all identical.

```
polys = Numerator[Values[f]];
pdiffs = Union[Flatten[Outer[Subtract, polys, polys]]];
FindMinimum[pdiffs.pdiffs, {x, 1}]

(* Out[451]= {0.0031283957326, {x -> 1.03846218702}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

A purely graphical approach for intersections:

```
Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];

plot = Plot[Evaluate @ Values @ f, {x, 0, 1.5}, PlotLegends -> (ToString /@ Keys[f])];

intersections = DeleteDuplicatesBy[Round[#, 10^-3]&] @ 
   Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[plot[[1]]];

listplot = ListPlot[List /@ intersections, BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
   PlotLegends -> (ToString[#, StandardForm] & /@ intersections)];

Show[plot, listplot, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]